# Random errors with (probably) Android support library

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When compiling Android project in Android Studio, I often get random errors like the following:

> Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\path_to_project\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015.png (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)

or

> Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\path_to_project\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha.png (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)

or

> Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\path_to_project\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000.png (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)

I don't explicitly use any of these resources, so it's probably the support library that's requiring them but somehow messing up. The errors are random - sometimes they don't appear, sometimes they do, for various files. Deleting contents of the build folder sometimes helps, sometimes not.

It is a really annoying issue because it appears randomly but when it does, it is quite time consuming "magic" to get rid of it. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I found some suggestions to disable antivirus program during compilation but that didn't work for me.

Comment: "cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open" means some program opens those files while your compile process tries to modify them. You could maybe find the offending thing on your pc by using ways mentioned in http://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows on a file that fails.

Comment: @zapl Thanks for the tip but nothing is found. Seems that nothing is locking those files for longer time, but only shortly (that would explain the randomness) but makes it impossible to find in the Process Explorer.

Comment: Besides anti-virus and other "security" software: I've seen similar issues when having files in a dropbox folder because it tries to sync those files.

Comment: @zapl That sounds like a good tip but unfortunately isn't my case.